# How to setup a DNS Seeds node and a Seed Node (for Litecoin clone)

Tags: litecoin, nodes, scrypt, fallback-nodes

I'm doing this for study purposes (creating a Litecoin clone). I read somewhere that for SCRYPT clones, the DNS Seeds nodes aren't necessary?

If I do need them, how to I setup these nodes. I know a DNS Seed node contains a list of IPs that are running a bitcoin client (in my case an alt-coin client).

Or is it enough to hard code one or more Ips in the client itself? Can I use a VPS for this?
Sorry for being noobish ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seed nodes are important even for SCRYPT coins.  You need to edit the source code in particular the DNS seeds and IP address seeds in the net.cpp file.  You can run this on a VPS or any always on internet connection with a static IP address.

[Litcoin Net.cpp](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/blob/master-0.8/src/net.cpp#L1190)

The DNS seed node resolves to multiple IP addresses that are all running their own *coind instance on the appropriate port.  To validate this perform an nslookup on one of the seed nodes.

```
C:\Windows\System32>nslookup dnsseed.litecointools.com.
Server:  dd-wrt
Address:  192.168.11.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    dnsseed.litecointools.com
Addresses:  109.67.99.8
          108.52.232.25
          .... (insert more here)
          23.242.146.169
          114.216.241.119
```

Comment: Yes, I have the net.cpp before me. Thanks for answering my question. So I have to install a VPS like dnsseed.servername.com that contains a page (like index.html) with the IP-address of a seed node (like node.servername.com). Can these reside on the same IP-address then?

Comment: Correct myself: I guess I need to have minimum 2 different IP-addresses then.

Comment: I have updated my answer with additional information regarding the DNS seed nodes and yes it can contain it's own IP as long as it is running an instance of the daemon with the full block chain (initially only the genesis block).